# How would I go thru my members list and remove ! from someone’s username?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my Discord Bot[v13] go thru all the members in the server and remove ! and extra spaces from theirs username. For example the bot would change someone nickname from `!  net-tech-` to just `net-tech-` by removing the `!` and extra spaces. So far I have

```
message.guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers => {
      const target_users = fetchedMembers.filter(member => member.user.username.startsWith("!"));
```

but I don't know how I would rename them to their name without `!` at the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fetch**
The first step would be to fetch all the members, which you've done so far.

**Filter**
Next filter all members with usernames that have `!` or any extra spaces.

If you want to replace only the `!` if they are at the start you would use `String#startsWith()`, for *any* `!` in the username use `String#includes()`.

To remove all extra spaces you can use the Regular Expression `/ +/g`

**Traverse**
Loop through the resulting members and change their nicknames

```js
const targetChar = '!';
const extraSpaces = / +/g;

message.guild.members.fetch().then(fetchedMembers => {
   // Use startsWith() for only starting "!", Use includes for any "!"
   const membersToRename = Array.from(fetchedMembers.filter(m => m.user.username.includes(targetChar) || m.user.username.match(extraSpaces).length));

   if (!membersToRename.length) return;

   // Use replace() for only the first, replaceAll() for all
   membersToRename.forEach(m => {
      const newNickname = m.user.username
         .replaceAll(targetChar, '')
         .replaceAll(extraSpaces, '');
      m.setNickname(newNickname)
         .catch(console.error);
   });
});
```

**Warning**
This could be considered API spam since you're changing information in masses, especially if used in large servers.

Comment: At replaceAll I get a typeerror: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')`.

Comment: Can you log `m` to ensure GuildMembers are returning

Comment: Done, yes they are returning good

Comment: Strange, the `.filter()` should of removed members who don't have a nickname. Try adding `if (!m.nickname) return;` right before `const newNickname ...`

Comment: The code he provided should check the username and the if the username has `!` should add a nickname right?

Comment: If you want to give them a *new* nickname based off their username I have edited my answer to reflect that

Comment: Now its a new error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')` at `m.username.match(extraSpaces).length));`

Comment: Make sure you're accessing `m.user.username` and not `m.username`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using string replace.
e.g.

```
var name = "! net-tech-"
// replace ! with "" and replace the space with ""
var newName = name.replace("!","").replace(" ","")
```

newName should give you "net-tech-"

Alternatively, you could use an if statement to check if the name starts with "!", e.g.

```
if (name[0] === "!") {
    // get the string from 2nd character onwards
    var newName = name.slice(1)
}
```